# MySQL query last 30 days sort by day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that I need to modify to use data variables to search counts for the last 30 days from today and group by date. My SQL server's `/tmp/` directory (15GB) keeps filling up and the query fails.

```
 SELECT DATE(`date_time`) AS DAY
, COUNT(DISTINCT(rcid)) AS COUNT
, COUNT(DISTINCT(tunnelip)) AS TAILS 
FROM primarydata 
WHERE SERVER LIKE"%VOE%" 
AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) and NOW() 
GROUP BY DAY;
```

Comment: Your query is only repeating the counts 30 times, not doing it for each of the 30 days that is the reason for it filling up the server, you need to link your date_sub with a date on the primarydata table

Comment: Which field in primary data represents the date for each record?

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the query manually in a shell? Looks like you're almost there. It may be failing on the group by. At this point in the execution it doesn't know what column DAY is.

Try: GROUP BY DATE(`date_time`)

Instead of: GROUP BY DAY.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  DATE(`date_time`)          AS DAY,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (rcid))     AS COUNT,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (tunnelip)) AS TAILS
FROM primarydata
WHERE SERVER LIKE
      "%VOE%" AND `date_time` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY `date_time`;
```

Comment: You need to reverse the `BETWEEN ` arguments. The low value has to be first.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, i adjusted that

Comment: @DRO, can you try again?

Comment: its not grouping tunnel counts by day,  I think what its doing is grouping by day every tunnel count per server. What is suppose to happen, is its suppose to fetch all tunnel counts for each server grouped by day, for the past 30 days

Answer (score 0):

Your date check is missing the column name to test, and also missing the `BETWEEN` keyword between the two dates.

```
SELECT
  DATE(`date_time`)          AS DAY,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (rcid))     AS COUNT,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (tunnelip)) AS TAILS
FROM primarydata
WHERE SERVER LIKE "%VOE%" 
    AND date_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY DAY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I got t to work using CURDATE()

> ```
>  AND `date_time` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30
> ```

```
SELECT
  DATE(`date_time`)          AS DAY,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (rcid))     AS COUNT,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (tunnelip)) AS TAILS
FROM primarydata
WHERE SERVER LIKE "%VOE%" AND `date_time` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() GROUP BY DAY;
```